# Tooltip doesnot adjust according to window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `Tipped` plugin for tooltip..as I have used a plugin before that is `ace admin plugin` and `Tipped` but the problem is it doesnot adjust position according to window size..In free tipped version some functionalities are not there..
Main problem I am getting is I have set tooltip on load and after checking condition I am try to change it but it shows both tooltip

Code :

```
var a=document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('id','23_34');
a.setAttribute('title', 'Transcription ID: ');  

 if (data == true) {
Tipped.remove("#23_45");
Tipped.create("#23_45", $('<p/>').html('Transcription ID:
}
```

and it shows both tooltip doesnot remove 1st one..any one have solution or suggest me any tooltip that automatic adjust it position according to window height?

Comment: Your js appears incomplete on the 2nd to last line

Comment: @OliverB in tipped document mention use id or class selector..is there any correction?

Comment: That bit is fine, but can't see the end of `$('<p/>').html('`... string and function are left unclosed. Why are you using `if(data==true)` for document ready by the way? Better to put it all inside a `$(function(){ ... })` if you want the bindings to occur when the page has loaded

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to use any plugin for tooltips and just **CSS** this answer could help.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" class="tooltip_custom" data-title="text on hover"></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tooltip_custom{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip_custom:hover:after{ 
    background: #333; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.9); 
    border-radius: 5px; bottom: 26px; 
    color: #fff; font-size: 12.2px; 
    content: attr(data-title); 
    left: 113%; 
    bottom:-30%; 
    padding: 4px 7px; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 500000000; 
    width: auto; 
} 
.tooltip_custom:hover:before{ 
    border: solid; 
    border-color: #333 transparent; 
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px; 
    bottom: 5px; 
    transform:rotate(90deg); 
    left: 100%; content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 5000000001; }
```

Comment: This is a good solution. In any case it's better not to have semantic content in the javascript - should be attached to the DOM target and retrieved dynamically if JS tooltips to be used.

Comment: But it doesnot adjust its position according to window..The main problem is that only

Comment: @niravpatel I dont want to use any plugin..your code is partially working..Is it automatic adjustable according to window size? and also I want to display tooltip at right side..plz help me

Comment: @debin I have edited answer for making the tooltip right sided. And for window size adjusting, I am not sure will check and get back soon.